# PIG script capability

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a Data processing requirement in Hadoop to validate the data in hdfs against another file which contains metadata about the valid values that the fields in the data files can conatin.

meta data has info as follows:

1 field1 - Boolean
2 field2 - Text
3 field3 - Number.

I need to iterate through each field in my data file and validate it against the metadata to see the values are valid.

Can such processing be done using PIG script?

Regards,
Nish

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a pig script, however you will need a UDF.

Comment: You could also implement your own load function that takes the metadata file as input and then validates data during load.

Comment: Thank you Fred and LiMuBei. I will attempt that.